# Gremlin query to find the count of a label for all the nodes

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

**Sample query**
The following query returns me the  count of a label say
"Asset " for a particular id  (0) has >>> 
**g.V().hasId(0).repeat(out()).emit().hasLabel('Asset').count()**

But I need to find the count for **all the nodes** that are present in the graph with a condition as above.

I am able to do it individually but my requirement is to get the count for all the nodes that has that label say 'Asset'.

So I am expecting some thing like

{ v[0]:2 
       {v[1]:1}
           {v[2]:1}
  }

where v[1] and v[2] has a node under them with a label say "Asset" respectively, making the overall count v[0] =2 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways you could do it. It's maybe a little weird, but you could use `group()`

```
g.V().
  group().
    by().
    by(repeat(out()).emit().hasLabel('Asset').count())
```

or you could do it with `select()` and then you don't build a big `Map` in memory:

```
g.V().as('v').
  map(repeat(out()).emit().hasLabel('Asset').count()).as('count').
  select('v','count')
```

if you want to maintain hierarchy you could use `tree()`:

```
g.V(0).
  repeat(out()).emit().
  tree().
    by(project('v','count').
         by().
         by(repeat(out()).emit().hasLabel('Asset')).select(values))
```

Basically you get a tree from vertex 0 and then apply a `project()` over that to build that structure per vertex in the tree. I had a different way to do it using `union` but I found a possible bug and had to come up with a different method (actually Gremlin Guru, Daniel Kuppitz, came up with the above approach). I think the use of `project` is more natural and readable so definitely the better way. Of course as Mr. Kuppitz pointed out, with `project` you create an unnecessary `Map` (which you just get rid of with `select(values)`). The use of `union` would be better in that sense.

Comment: Thanks Stephen !! But is there a way I can get the result in a hierarchical way

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Maybe I got confused by "all the nodes...in the graph" - do you mean all the nodes underneath vertex 0?

Comment: i think i have the answer to your question now - please see my edited answer